# State doesn't update until polling occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the state being initialized and is passed down into a child component:

```
const [rowCount, setRowCount] = React.useState<number>(1);

<Foo setRowCount={setRowCount} />
```

Foo:

```
const Foo = (props) => {
  const { setRowCount } = props;

  const count = React.useRef<number>(0);

  useEffect(() => {
      setRowCount(rowCount.current);
  }, [count.current]);

  const bars: Bar[] = A.map(( bar ) => bar);

  count.current = bar.length;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that `rowCount` is not being updated until a refetch occurs despite `rowCount.current` being set at line `count.current = bar.length`

I'm not sure if it's because I'm using `useEffect` incorrectly or if there is some other oversight. Please let me know if I can provide more detail.

Comment: For something like a number, you should use useState. This will also let you rerender on setState. UseRef only safes the reference but does not listen to updates to it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

**UseEffect** run when state change. You are using useRef for count . **useRef** is used when u need a variable or dom reference  but u dont need any rerender . So if u need any rerender and need invocation of **useEffect** after changing a state . Then use useState.

```
const [count, setCount] = React.useState<number>(1);
```